# Anybody know what kind of bug/cricket this thing is? I can't narrow it down enough

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Spotted just walking about down the road.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site, please take a [tour] and visit the [help] to learn what makes a good question to be asked here. Specifically for identification purposes we need good quality photos, preferably from several angles, a location (general, district/county level would be good), and an approximate size.

Comment: Grasshopper, immature, I do not know the specific species.

Comment: Location is the U.S. I have a video but the site would not let me post it.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include **all** the requested information (hover over or click on the species-identification tag for details) — comments are ephemeral and often overlooked so they should not be used to convey important information. In addition, as mentioned by @bob1 we need a location much more specific than "U.S." — as a random example, the fauna of central Texas and costal Maine are very different! I believe there are services that will convert (portions of) a video into a GIF that can be included — you may also include a link to the full video.

Comment: @ErgoNot try using a site like [ezgif.com](https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif) to convert your video to a gif (which *can* be uploaded into your post. Just make sure you optimize it to be <2mb for the system to allow it to be included in your post.

Comment: It could be a immature lubber grasshopper ( adults look rather different).